# Admin and user Login in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to allow both user and login through one view but when a user login he should be directed to another view and when user logins he should be directed to another view.
Here is my database:
[image: Database]

I have made simple registration but I need to make a login form where depending on the role the user gets directed to the views.
[image: Registration Form]

i have made a login stored procedure:

```
 Create  procedure [dbo].[Login]  
(
@Username nvarchar (20),
@Password nvarchar (20)
)
as
Begin
Select COUNT(*)from Users where Username=@Username and Password=@Password
End
```

and Login.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication19.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and a ValidateUser function

```
 public bool Validate_User(Login lmodel)
        {

            connection();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Login");

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", lmodel.Username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", lmodel.Password);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                    if (i >= 1)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;


        }
    }
```

i dont understand how to use roles in my code.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: As a side note - [Password] column nvarchar(20)... Try not to learn to store passwords in plaintext. Okay if you are just learning but please do bear this in mind

Comment: @JonathanWillcock you can check my edited question.

Comment: @Milney Yes i will change it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be trying to provide a solution keeping your existing structure and using only 1 DB call.

Ok firstly, change your login procedure to return the UserRole instead of count (count really serves no purpose in the case of a login). So something like this:

```
Create  procedure [dbo].[Login]  
(
@Username nvarchar (20),
@Password nvarchar (20)
)
as
Begin
    Select Role from Users where Username=@Username and Password=@Password
End
```

Next, you will need to amend your `Validate_User` function... into something like this:

```
public bool Validate_User(Login lmodel, out string userRole)
    {
        connection();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Login");

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", lmodel.Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", lmodel.Password);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                userRole = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(userRole);


    }
}
```

At this point, you now have your role and the logic around the bool (userIsValid) should still be consistent. You now just need to call Validate_User and retrieve the user's role. That should look something like this:

```
string role = string.empty;

if (Validate_User(loginModel, out role))
{
    if (role == "Admin")
    {
        return View("AdminView");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("UserView");
    }
}
else
{
    //handle failed login
}
```

Hope this helps you, didn't give this a test, but it should work fine.

Bare in mind, you will need to do a `RedirectToAction` if there is more logic that needs to run or data that needs to be returned specific to the view. If it is just a page to load, you can just return `View`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an asp.net core project from a template with authorization and investigate how it should be done. In your case, you can use Redirect Action in you controller methods but it's not a great practice, anyway take a look at [this link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **RedirectToAction()** method, then the action you redirect to can return a View. The easiest way to do this is:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
```

If you do not need to return a model, clear it

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: but how should i redirect different view to the admin/user depending on their role(field in User database)

Comment: please see this link :https://stackoverflow.com/a/25448076/5576498

Comment: @BushraAkram you can check role before redirect and select proper view.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to redirect Visitor to different pages depending on their Role. So for that Assign Role like "Admin", "User".

After that When You Check Login at that time fetch role.

```
var roles = "Select Role from Users where Username=@Username and Password=@Password";

if(roles == "Admin"){
//redirect to admin view
}
else{
//redirect to user view
}
```

Comment: Not a very straight forward answer, how does the SQL string `roles` change suddenly? OP is also using a stored proc, so the SQL should be sitting there.

Comment: you can get "roles" from SP too.

Answer (score 0):

As far a i can understand what you want is role based authentication in our MVC application.

You will assign role while registering your user and when they will login then based on its role you will open different pages.

You can check out the below link for the same, it will be helpful for you.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/role-based-access-of-an-mvc-application/